# Своя переменная в шаблоне ActiveForm -> fieldConfig -> template

Tags: php, yii2

Такая ситуация, к примеру у меня есть форма

```html
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([

   'id' => 'login-form',
   'method' => 'post',
   'action' => ['site/signup'],
   'options' => ['class' => 'userForm form registration'],

   'fieldConfig' => [
    'template' =>
     "<div class='element'>\n" .
      "<div class='input-content'>" .
       "{label}\n" .
       "<i class='input-image'></i>\n" .
       "{input}\n" .
      "</div>\n" .
     "</div>\n",
    'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'element-label'],
   ]
  ]);?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')
   ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Введите логин'])
  ; ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'email')
   ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Введите email'])
  ; ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

В данной форме все элементы выводятся по шаблону `fieldConfig->template`, могу ли я в каждом элементе формы добавлять переменную и выводить в шаблоне, не меняя весь шаблон?

К примеру

```html
'template' =>
    "<div class='element {MYVARIABLE}'>\n" .
     "<div class='input-content'>" .
      "{label}\n" .
      "<i class='input-image'></i>\n" .
      "{input}\n" .
     "</div>\n" .
    "</div>\n",

//set variable 
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')
            ->setVar('MYVARIABLE', '1') // что то типо того 
   ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Введите логин'])
  ; ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'email')
->setVar('MYVARIABLE', '2') // что то типо того 
   ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Введите email'])
  ; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1-е. Создай свой (новый класс) формы `MyActiveField` наследующий `ActiveForm` и расширяющий его с нужным методом (геттер/сеттер) и аттрибутом.

View:

```
<?php
    $form->fieldClass='app\components\form\MyActiveField';
    $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->setMyVar('akinawa');
?>
```

app\components\form\MyActiveField.php

```
<?php
namespace app\components\form;

        class MyActiveField extends yii\widgets\ActiveForm
        {
            private $myVar;

            public function setMyVar($var)
            {
                $this->myVar = $var;
                return $this;
            }
        }
?>
```